Should HEC token in Splunk be encrypted?
I am sending logs to Splunk, during peer review I got question if we shouldn't encrypt token.
Does it make sense to encrypt HEC token? It's not any secret, if I understand correctly.
<appender name="SPLUNK" class="com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender">
            <url>https://url.net:8088/</url>
            <token>abcde-123-sv-vndsv</token>
            <source>${source}</source>
            <sourcetype>service</sourcetype>
            <host>${hostname}</host>
            <messageFormat>text</messageFormat>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%msg </pattern>
            </layout>
</appender>


Do not encrypt the token.  An encrypted token would not be recognized and cause the request to fail.  Since you're using TLS, encryption of just the token is unnecessary.
If you mean to encrypt the token when at rest then that's a reasonable precaution.

by encrypting here I though about encrypt it in code so it's not in plaintext, e.g take it from EVA or other keystore. During transmission that would be decoded of course

I agree with storing the token in a protected format or store.
